# Create custom image by using a small piece of image

Tags: javascript, php, image, laravel, gd

I am looking to create a custom layout by using a small piece of image.

> For Example: I have a piece of image 30*30 px now I need to create a new image of 200*200 px (that actually be a frame like photo frame).

I have researched a lot of gd library of php but did not find any way to do that.

I just need an way that how can I achieve that.

There is a live example of my need: https://www.pictureframesexpress.co.uk/picture-frame-designer/?stage=1

Can some one please tell me the way to achieve this in php (I am using laravel4).

Thanks in advance for your kind support.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with html and css. That would be sufficient for it.
Just build a markup structure around the image, e.g. a div-element as parent. If you need to support older browsers (non CSS3) then look for "sliding doors" technique in css. If not you can assign multiple background-images (in your case the diffrent borders of the frame) to the div that contains your 30x30-image.

Sliding doors:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/perfect-css-sprite-sliding-doors-button/

multiple background images:

https://css-tricks.com/css3-multiple-backgrounds-obsoletes-sliding-doors/

Comment: Can same one please help me to do above functionality through PHP.